# Better performing sql code for extracting data to a file?

Tags: sql, oracle

I work with datasets that exceeds the millions on a daily basis, most of my work I do at this stage is to write code for extracting the data from the databases into files for other users to use in their business intelligence divisions.

The code that  I am currently using is a basic FOR loop which looks like this:

```
for x in cursor_body 
    loop
    utl_file.put_line(out_file_filename, x.data_line);
    end loop;
```

This takes hours to complete at this stage and I need something that moves a bit faster since this will run on a weekly basis and we have other unix bash jobs that has to run as well.

I've read up on some solutions using a little C or Java to do more efficient date extracts, but I am wondering if there isn't a PL/SQL or SQL way of doing it faster.

Your inputs will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to partition your query and run it in parallel and then merge the files at the end?

Comment: This blog article (http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=425) tries to tune for a scenario similar to yours. Maybe you will find some help from there

Comment: Another thing which you can do (along with other hacks which you might need) is to use Parallel hint in the cursor for unloading data. That will give you good enough performance boost, but again you will have to check for its usage in your particular scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it works better when you write everything into a CLOB and then write it to disc:

```
DECALRE
    UTF8 BOOLEAN TRUE;
    BUFFER VARCHAR2(4096 CHAR);
    offset PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    FileLength PLS_INTEGER;
    amount BINARY_INTEGER := 1024;
    fhandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

    TXT CLOB;

BEGIN

FOR aLine IN cursor_body LOOP
   DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(TXT, LENGTH(aLine.data_line), aLine.data_line);
END LOOP;

FileLength := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(TXT);
IF UTF8 THEN
    fhandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR(FolderName, FileName, open_mode => 'w', max_linesize => 32000);
ELSE
    fhandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(FolderName, FileName, open_mode => 'w', max_linesize => 32000);
END IF;

LOOP
    EXIT WHEN offset > FileLength;
    DBMS_LOB.READ(TXT, amount, offset, BUFFER);
    IF UTF8 THEN
        UTL_FILE.PUT_NCHAR(fhandle, BUFFER);
    ELSE
        UTL_FILE.PUT(fhandle, BUFFER);
    END IF;
    UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(fhandle);
    offset := offset + amount;
END LOOP;
UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fhandle);


DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(TXT);

END;
```